# webcam "still pin" capture

Tags: c++, directshow, webcam, video-capture

I am trying to replicate the image quality that is achieved when using the Logitech webcam driver to capture a still image.

The Logitech forum has several threads about the subject unfortunately they all point to a website which is down. such as [here](http://forums.logitech.com/t5/Webcams/Snapshot-button/td-p/712224).

I am currently able to use DirectShow and a frame grabber to capture images, but they are nowhere near the quality of the snapshot button. Could anyone point me to the direction of a working c++/c example of a snapshot button?

After some research I found this about the [Still Image pin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318622%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), is this the correct method for implementing a snapshot like button?

The webcam I am using the c910 and is capable of taking 10 mega-pixel still images.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does c910 really have CMOS of 10 mpixels?

Comment: @Daniel: it's perhaps 2MP picture, 4x oversampled and post-processed.

Comment: You are taking 2mp pictures (what's the resolution?) from it with frame grabber?  At what rate?

Comment: the camera can take raw 5mp images at 5fps, but yes I have it set to 1080 which is 2mp

Answer (score 1):

My best guess, which I'll use to gather some upvotes (or downvotes), and which will be valid until someone disassembles the application or the driver, is:

Something alike http://www1.idc.ac.il/toky/videoproc-07/projects/superres/srproject.html was used at the application level to enhance the resolution of the images collected as a video.

Rationale: having a friend pulling his hair over simpler things inside the driver, I can only imagine how difficult it should be to code such an algorithm INSIDE the driver with extremely limited set of libraries.

I won't mind taking downvotes here, since I'm too interested in this subject, but please have some information available on the subject.

Comment: yes, it does, but with some clicking around I was able to get to .m sources.

Answer (score 0):

I did not have a chance to deal with this directly, however I suspect that high resolution images captured from the camera are a result of taking a sequence of images followed by "superresolution" post-processing. This functionality might be unavailable via DirectShow API, since it mostly covers video streaming. However, the camera driver might also make it available via [`Windows Image Acquisition` API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663279%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), where you might have better luck taking oversampled snapshots of the quality you are looking for.